# Corollary of Kolmogorov's Consistency Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Refer to https://sip.math.uni-heidelberg.de/vl/wt2-ss16/assets/src/VL1_2-WT2-SS16.pdf, 2.3.13:

I don't know how to show the existence of independent family $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ of random variables such that $PX_t^{-1}=\mu_t$ for all $t\in I$ where $I$ is infinite index set.

I know that $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ of real r.v.'s is independent iff for every finite $J\subset I$ and every $x=(x_j)_{j\in J}\in \mathbb{R}^J$, $F_J(x)=\prod_{j\in J}F_j(x_j)$. Then, I could assume a finite $J\subset I$ and let $\mathbb{P}_F:=\otimes_{t\in F}\mathbb{P}_t$. But I'm confused with this question.

Can anyone give me some hints or show me how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to verify that the family $\{P_F\}$ is consistent? Where exactly are you having difficulty?

Comment: I know that for finite $F\subset I$, it is consistent under some conditions related to other finite set. However, I don't know how to relat to the independent family of random variables.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't know where I should start with.

Comment: Some outlines or steps may help a lot